# It is possible an ethernet connection point work for a PC and fail for another?

Tags: router, ip, ethernet, lan

Before I go ahead from this point and solve my LAN connection problem by trying alternatives sequentially until it works, I would like to understand this.

I have a single LAN Ethernet point where I am now, and I use the cable when working with some old PC. This point is working ok with my Macbook Pro and was working with this PC. It has an ethernet port onboard and a Realtek PCI card for another port. None is working after I change a lot of things (change video card, HDD, memories, flash the BIOS etc. plus I had to change setting in the BIOS to accomplish the upgrade). The PC does not connect to my LAN by any of those ports. The system (I try Windows XP, 7 and Xubuntu) detects the cable inserted but fail to connect.

This Ethernet point is not very good, I had to open the box to manage the cable until it works. However, after establish the connection in my Mac, I just move the cable to the PC but it can't connect. The binary conclusion is a PC problem, but two bad ethernet ports at the same time? Three bad OS configs?

Back to the ethernet point, before I start to move my PC around the house to test another point, I would like to know if it is possible this point is bad but the Mac still can connect because it does in a different way.

Comment: "detects the cable inserted but fail to connect." - what exactly is the output of ipconfig /all, disconnected or what? Perhaps it is just a configuration issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mac does not connected in any different way then the other machines. It's possible that you've accidentally changed settings for the LAN on your other machines, such as IP ranges, netmasks, Jumbo sizes, link speeds, packet sizes - there's a whole host of settings to change and if any one of those are wrong the connection won't establish. It's likely working on the Mac because it's config is correct while the other machines are not. I'd suggest looking at the system documentation for both Windows and Xubuntu/Ubuntu/Whatever Linux distro you're using and determine whether the settings match those that are defined by either the network or your Mac. Have a look at the links below for configuring the network and your network adapter(s). On Windows, you can access your network adapters settings through device manager, and the links below are for Windows.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15089/windows-change-tcp-ip-settings
http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/netgeneral/advanced-network-adapter-driver-settings.html

Comment: … _refresh rates_?

Comment: buffers and link speeds are the same as refresh rates right? XD I was thinking about wireless, should probably change my answer

Comment: The first link is not very useful, though, only for a simple problem. In my case was the duplex (speed settings) - must be set as half. If I set to "auto" it will try full duplex, as my Mac, but won't work, don't know why. Maybe some setting in the bridge is preventing from ethernet PCI card from work in full duplex, and the onboard ethernet is really dead. But I set the answer as right because your point is correct: there is no difference and before changing hardware, we must look deep every detail of connections, not only the basics.